# JS - Google analytics - dimension cities in GB

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to display all the cities in England using dimension to get analytics.
However it does not seems to work. If I use 'city' instead of 'city GB' the output is a geo map with all cities in the world placed in the GB region (see image attached). How can I limit the search to just uk cities?
[image]

```
var chart2 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:city GB',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '2daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'GEO',
      container: 'timeline2',
      options: {
        region: 'GB', // Western Europe
        displayMode: 'markers',
        magnifyingGlass: 'enable: true, zoomFactor: 7.5'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can't you just add a filter to the query that limits the query to the UK, i.e. adding "ga:country==United Kingdom" to the query object ? Or if you actually mean England the filter would be ga:region==England.

Comment: not working error:  {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"Invalid dimension or metric: ga:country==United Kingdom"}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid dimension or metric: ga:country==United Kingdom"}}

Comment: In works in the query explorer (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/). You would need to add a "filter" property to your query ("filter":"ga:country==United Kingdom"), not add it to the dimensions - is that what you did and it still didn't work ?